# Cannot load data from DynamoDB due to an attribute of type List<Object> which is not able to get unconverted and was saved using @DynamoDBDocument

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to save a `List<CustomObject>` using the @DynamoDBDocument but it gives me a DynamoDBMappingException : could not unconvert attribute.

Here is what my Entity class looks like -

```
@lombok.Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "carTable")
public class Car {
   @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "name")
   private carName;

   @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "model")
   private carModel;

   @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "manufacturers")
   private List<Manufacturer> manufacturers;
}
```

The Manufacturer class looks like -

```
@lombok.Data
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Manufacturer {
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String manufacturerName;
}
```

When using this entity and saving the values into the table it saves properly as JSON, but when retrieving it, an exception is thrown -

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Car[manufacturers]; could not unconvert attribute
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:271)
[junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:456)
[junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:422)
[junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:433)
[junit]     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:85)
```

What am I missing here, do I need to add some sort of TypeConverter or Marshaller here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A no-args constructer was required to unconvert the attribute, adding @lombok.NoArgsConstructor to the Manufacturer class solved my problem.

Comment: Could you please explain where in the manufacturer class that you add @lombok.NoArgsConstructor?

Comment: You can add the `@lombok.NoArgsConstructor` on the top of your class just like `@lombok.Data` is present in the example. Here you can add it above `Data`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a custom converter here, it looks like that DynamoDB has some issues with converting DynamoDB item into a Java object.

Check:

- Data in DynamoDB matches your object fields. Check if types are matching as well
- What if you define setters explicitly? Maybe Lombok is a culprit here?

Also it is odd that you do not specify a table name here:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName)
public class Car {
...
}
```

Comment: Might have missed the table name while writing the example here, added it to the question.
I've verified lombok is not the culprit here, it gives me same error when defining setters explicitly.
The data in db looks like this - 
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "model": "abc",
  "manufacturers": [
    {
      "manufacturerName": "mf1"
    }
  ]
}
I think it is how it is supposed to be. Now I am doubting if @DynamoDBDocumented works for a List of custom objects in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that the setters were missing

This was because I was using Lombok with @Builder and @Getter annotations only

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Builder, you can still use @Tolerate to add default Constructor

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my java class had an attribute as string, whereas dynamodb was storing it as a number. When I changed my attribute to be a ***int*** instead of a ***string***, it worked smoothly.